# word wrap in combo box angularjs

Tags: angularjs, combobox, responsive-design

In my `Angularjs` application, I've a combobox to get client's info but some of clients' names are too long that it affects the whole design like this;

[image]

> It doesn't even add any horizontal scroll-bar to it so one can read
>   full name.

I did RnD on it but didn't find anything related to it. So we cannot handle this issue in any way? or I'm missing something here?

**Updated : Code**

This is my html to show client dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" id="cmbClients" name="cmbClients" ng-model="cmbClientsSelected" ng-options="client.clientName for client in lstAllClients | orderBy : 'clientName'" ng-keydown="cmbClients_KeyDown($event)" > 
    <option value=""> -- Select --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you using `<select>`. Please share sample code

Comment: Well, there is only one word, so it can't be wrapped. If you want, you can use the ellipsis on overflowing text using a CSS rule. But, first of all, share your code.

Comment: my bad. Please check updated question. Code added

Comment: I think this snippet is what you need [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/NJRlvem5jnVVMvpE9Etf?p=preview)

Comment: but it still does not show the whole name/ value

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this by using the default `select` HTML element. You could achieve this by using a custom select like [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select). Those allows word-breaks inside an option.

#### View

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.0/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/master/src/select2.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    No Results Tag: {{ noResultsTag }}
    <select style="width: 400px;" ui-select2="select2Options" ng-model="selectedTags">
        <option ng-repeat="tag in tags" value="{{tag.id}}">{{tag.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.select2']);

function MyCtrl($scope, $compile, $timeout) {
    $scope.tags = [
        {id: 0, name: "Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero"},
        {id: 1, name: "One"},
        {id: 2, name: "Two"}, 
        {id: 3, name: "Three"}, 
        {id: 4, name: "Four"}, 
    ];
    $scope.select2Options = {
        formatNoMatches: function(term) {
            var message = '<a ng-click="addTag()">Add tag:"' + term + '"</a>';
            if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.noResultsTag = term;
                });
            }
            return message;
        }
    };
}
```

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppgkt0hp/)**

Comment: it does work but this is not what I want because I've to make a lot of changes in my code..

Comment: @NullPointer this is up on you. But you can't fix your problem without making any changes. As I said, you can't achieve what you want by using the default HTML select element. So, stay with your problem or start coding :)

Comment: ofcourse I'll make changes in my code but in different way. like increase length of combo-box or put a specific character length to client name .. Or may be someone else come up with any other work-around

Comment: @NullPointer good luck by searching a neat solution. Please share it with use once you get it.

Comment: Sure I will definitely share